# Android dependencies inconsitant

Tags: java, android

I am using firebase database and have updated my dependencies.

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'}
```

I keep getting the following error:

> A/FirebaseApp: Firebase API initialization failure.
>                                                                  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696)
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5045)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4630)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4570)
>                                                                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method)
>                                                                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:729)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication()
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1383)
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5300)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
>                                                                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
>                                                                   Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.zzeC(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzg.(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzd.zzb(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance(Unknown Source)
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zza(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zzbu(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1696) 
>                                                                      at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1671) 
>                                                                      at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(Unknown Source) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5045) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4630) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4570) 
>                                                                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.invokeOriginalMethodNative(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.handleHookedMethod(XposedBridge.java:729) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication() 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:154) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1383) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5300) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904) 
>                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699) 
>                                                                      at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:133)
>
> E/FA: Task exception on worker thread: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: The method 'java.io.File android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getNoBackupFilesDir(android.content.Context)' was expected to be of type virtual but instead was found to be of type direct (declaration of 'java.lang.reflect.ArtMethod' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar): com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzEd(Unknown Source)

But if I change these dependencies back to version 23 instead of 24 and run after rebuilding gradle:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'}
```

I dont get the above error but still get:

D/FirebaseInstanceId: background sync failed: SERVICE_NOT_AVAILABLE

Everything was working fine untill I updated android studio

The complete build, gradle looks like the following:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"


defaultConfig {
    applicationId "pvn.com.locanews"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE-FIREBASE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}}dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.0.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.3.1'}
```

Stuck..............

Comment: can you post complete app's `build.gradle` file?

Comment: edited the question with full build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

Try if this solution.Basically I had two libraries modules - that happened to be of my own - each one of them importing different versions of com.android.support:appcompat-v7.* and google play services. Made all of them import the same version and problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

I corrected the dependencies to:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'}
```

Firebase works only with v7:23.4.0

Any other and it will give "API initialization error"

the compileSDKVersion and buildToolsVersion is 23.

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this error by upgrade firebase-core:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.2'
```